# Opening an eclipse project in Intellij IDEA 13 (Linux)

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, intellij-idea, environment

I'm not trying to convert or import a project, I simply want to open a .project or .classpath file... but it's just not working for some reason. I don't know if IDEA is broken, or if something is different on linux than it is on Windows...

I've checked out from our SVN repository the project that I'm working on, and it says something along the lines of (I don't have it on my screen anymore) "IDEA project found (.classpath) Do you want to open it?". I click yes, and then nothing. I try to click "open project" and select the .classpath or the .project file, and again, nothing happens. Some kind of status popup window seems to flash very quickly, but then it just goes back to the intro window where I can open/import/create new projects.

Comment: I've always had this kind of problem but in windows and I solve it by importing the project, there you have an option to import from Eclipse. Here it's a link that might be useful. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-eclipse-projects-into-intellij-idea.html

Answer (score 0):

Under the `File` menu, select `Import Project...`

Then, select the **directory** that contains the `.project` and `.classpath` files (don't select the files themselves).  It will then open the eclipse project in IntelliJ for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had this kind of problem, but in windows and I solve it by importing the project, there you have an option to import from Eclipse. Here it's a link that might be useful. [Jetbrains Idea Help.](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-eclipse-projects-into-intellij-idea.html)